# Why does accessing element of boost::ptr_vector try to instantiate new object?

Tags: c++, boost

I have changed my code from using a

```
std::vector<A*>
```

to using a

```
boost::ptr_vector<A>
```

and have come up against a problem.

Here's the code:

```
class A
{
protected:
    virtual int getNumber() {return 1;};

public:

    static int getSum( boost::ptr_vector<A> &pv){
        int sum = 0;
        for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != pv.size(); i++) {
            sum += pv[i].getNumber();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    virtual ~A(void)=0;
}
```

Now, since changing to the ptr_vector, I get a compiler error:

```
error C2259: 'A' : cannot instantiate abstract class
due to following members:
'A::~A(void)' : is abstract
```

on the line

```
sum += pv[1].getNumber();
```

This is my first time using ptr_vector so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but why is it trying to instantiate, and how can it be avoided?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the code where the A objects are created and assigned to the ptr_vector.

Comment: Any chance for an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) that can reproduce the problem?  I [attempted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bea89e4c6ac9fc6f) to reproduce the compiler error, but was unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the comments were correct in that the problem actually lay in where the A objects were being created.

I had a class, B, which had ptr_vector as a member. B populated the vector only with objects derived from A, which was fine.

The problem came about when a copy of B was made. As A was not cloneable, this caused the error.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have pure virtual and not defined destructor for class, it you want to use it polymorphically. `ptr_vector` should clean its contents (default policy is calling of `delete` on pointer, that call destructor of object, so destructor should be defined).

Try to define it after class declaration (or in cpp file) like

```
A::~A() {}
```

n3376 12.4/9

> A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); **if
>   any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the
>   program, the destructor shall be defined.**

Comment: It worked with vector<A*> because vector does not worry about creation/deletion. However from the limited code sample here pv could easily hold objects that are derived from A and do define a valid destructor. Therefore it is still unclear to me why this fails to compile.